# How to populate the subsequent choice fields in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm a Django beginner and I've been through the clever-select and chained-selects, but can't just seem to tinker it for my purpose.
Let's say I have a model something like this:

```
class XYZ(models.Model):
    ...
    attribute1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    attribute2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    attribute3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    attribute4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    attribute5 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    ...
```

What I am planning to do is to create a template where I can house a set of dropdowns, which will be linked to the above-said attributes. Initially, the first dropdown will contain the values of `attribute1`, retrieved from the database, and based on the selected value, `attribute2` dropdown should be populated with relevant values.

Answer (score 0):

The key phrase here is "based on the selected value." Django is a server side framework, and does not know of any events happening on the client side (browser) once the page is loaded except for explicit requests. You will need to use JavaScript and listen for the first drop down to be updated, and then filter the options for drop down 2 accordingly, still using JavaScript.